# Custom C++ header error undefined reference to `ClientData::ClientData

Tags: c++

I am Starting learning C++ from scratch, and now I am trying to import this custom header to one of my cpp. Its a pretty basic class.

**ClientData.h**

```
#ifndef CLIENTDATA_H
#define CLIENTDATA_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ClientData{
public:
    ClientData(int=0, const string & = "", const string & = "", double = 0);

    void setAccountNumber(int);
    int getAccountNumber() const;

    void setLastName(const string &);
    string getLastName() const;

    void setFirstName(const string &);
    string getFirstName() const;

    void setBalance(double);
    double getBalance() const;

private:
    int accountNumber;
    char lastName[15];
    char firstName[10];
    double balance;
};

#endif
```

**tutor.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "ClientData.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
  ClientData blankClient;
  return 0;
}
```

I get an error of: `undefined reference to ClientData::ClientData(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, double)`

For an extra info: I am using **MinGW Compiler**, and I also name the header **ClientData.h** placed under the include folder of MinGW Compiler directory. I run this code under sublime text.

What should I do to solve this? Thankyou

Comment: What command did you use to build/compile your project? Also, show us your source file(.cpp)

Comment: The error message means that you have not defined your `ClientData` constructor. None of the code you have posted contains a `ClientData` constructor definition. So either you don't have such a definition or you have not posted all the code you have. Do you think you have defined the `ClientData` constructor?

Comment: I see so this section of code `ClientData(int=0, const string & = "", const string & = "", double = 0);` is not enough to be called constructor.. @john thanks, yes I still make an "outline" of it first in this practice, to see if its valid or no.

Comment: @Jovan The code you are referring to is a *declaration* not a *definition*. Understanding the difference is crucial here.

Comment: @John Noted, I have filled the definition of the class, and now the header include is working